# nearest meeting node of two given nodes in a Directed Graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, directed-graph

I am given a Directed Graph and given two nodes in it I need to find the nearest node  that can be reached from both of them. The only problem is I am able to do it with two dfs but I was told to do it in O(logn). Additional constraint is that each cell can have **at most one** outgoing edge. Input is given as an array of size N where eachentry in array denotes the index of node this node is leading to. So for this is the code I have tried(not exactly dfs but still):

```
int leastCommonDescendent(int nodes[], int N, int node1, int node2)
{
  int *visited = new int [N];
  int cnt1 = 0; //used for counting length of path from node1 to node2
  int cnt2 = 0; //used for counting length of path from node2 to node1
  int mark = node1; //storing as a marker needed later for detecting end of search

  if(node1 == node2) return node2;
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    visited[i] = 0;
  }

  while((nodes[node1] != node1) && (nodes[node1] != -1) && (visited[node1] == 0) && (node1 != node2)){
    visited[node1]++;
    node1 = nodes[node1];
    cnt1++;
  }

  visited[node1]++; //so that first node in cycle has count 2
                    //if find a node in 2nd iteration that has count 2
                    //such that when node1 == node2 it means we are in the same subgraph
                    //elsif node1 != node2 we are in different sub graphs

  while((nodes[node2] != node2) && (nodes[node2] != -1) && (visited[node2] != 2) && (node1 != node2)){
    visited[node2]++;
    node2 = nodes[node2];
    cnt2++;
  }
  //In below case the nodes are in different disjoint subgraphs
  //and both subgraphs have loops so node1 can never be equal to node2
  //cout << visited[node1] << visited[node2] << endl;
  if(node1 != node2) return -1;
    //In below case both nodes are in different disjoint subgraphs
    //but there is no loop in 1st one(containing node1)
    //and 2nd one has a loop
  if ((nodes[node1] == -1) && (visited[node2] == 1)) return -1;
    //In below case both nodes are in different disjoint subgraphs
    //but 1st one has a loop and second one doesn't
  if(nodes[node2] == -1) return -1;
    //In below case both nodes are in same subgraph so we
    //need to check the length of two alternate paths
  if(cnt1 > cnt2)
    return node2;
  else
    return mark;
}
```

Suppose I have a component of a graph(essentially a subgraph) like following:
[image]

In this case if I want to find the nearest node from 7 & 9 I am getting the answer 9 while it should be 8. Though I understand it is because I have condition cell1 != cell2 in both loops but I am going for entire cycle in case I remove that which invites more time. Also I feel this solution as cluttered with multiple if's. Can we have a simpler solution? (possibly **O(logn)** based)

This graph can also have cycles as illustrated by image above. So converting to tree is not possible I guess.

Comment: Does it work? If not, why and where do you think it does not work?

Comment: It's impossible to do that in O(logN) time

Comment: Please provide a link to your problem.

Comment: @PhamTrung Unfortunately there is no link, it was an interview problem. I have tried to narrate as much as I remembered

Answer (score 2):

This is easily reduced to (and from) [Lowest Common Ancestor in a tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor) (or in a forest to be exact), by simply reversing the links of your graph.

Generally, it can be done in `O(h)`, by stepping "up" the tree step by step (stepping forward in the original graph), and storing found nodes in a set until the set intersecton is not empty.

If pre-processing is allowed, one can pre-process it in linear time to get better resilts.

Comment: Please see the edit. What if this graph has a cycle?

Comment: @sky_coder123 DAG is directed **acyclic** graph, how can it have a cycle?

Comment: Oh sorry about that . Actually I was not able to formulate it properly within the stipulated time when I started solving this as the question was in the words of competitive coding. I have changed the tags to reflect the same.

Comment: @PhamTrung Even DAG can have cycles just that it does not have directed cycles.